# Why is are some NuGet commands only accessible when using Package Manager Console and seemingly not available as part of the nuget CLI?

Tags: nuget

I can use NuGet from Cmd via prefixing commands with `nuget ...` as one would expect.

But then it seems like there are certain commands that have to be executed explicitly from the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio. For example, `Update-package -reinstall`.

Why is this? Am I using two different versions of NuGet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By NuGet CLI I take it that you mean [NuGet.exe](https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe). The difference that you are noticing is by design.

The NuGet CLI is a commandline tool which supports commands like restore, pack, install etc. You need to invoke it using `nuget` because that is the name of the tool.
The Package Manager Console in Visual Studio is a wrapper around Powershell and the the commands are consistent with the powershell cmdlet [guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878238(v=vs.85).aspx).

It is possible that you are using different versions. You can check this by -

1. NuGet CLI - 
   Please run `nuget help` E.g. -
   [image]
2. Package Manager Console - 
   When you launch the console in VIsual Studio, it should display the version. E.g. - 
   [image]

Comment: thanks - I had not heard of the idea of `Cmdlet`s before

Comment: What is the benefit of creating a wrapper around Powershell vs using an executable like `NuGet.exe`? If the .exe is added to a user's $PATH variable it would seem to me that it is vastly superior? And also less confusing. And seemingly inline with the holy grail of operating systems that Windows will one day compete with on the server front - `Linux` ;)

Comment: The goal of Package Manager Console was to provide a console experience built into Visual Studio. Adding different cmdlets was done because NuGet.exe did not ship inside VS and was meant to be a standalone experience.

Comment: i have found that it's easier to use a standard terminal - this one: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DanielGriffen.WhackWhackTerminal. I have to have both the terminal open and the package manager cmdlet open though